# Getting the time of the last sent packet from a network card

Tags: c#

I am truly stumped on how to grab the time the last packet got sent off a network interface, anyone out there hacked there way through this guy before?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: quite literally the requirement is to display the Date / Time the last packet was sent.

Comment: I don't believe that information is stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible unless that info was sent along as well.

If you do have access to that computer, why not add a code to send along the date time?

Comment: I assumed from the vagueness of the question he was asking about *any* packet.

Comment: Your correct, and the vagueness of the question stems from the wonderfully vague requirements :X

Comment: I'm not very sure if they do append additional info to any packets. But let me give you an analogy. Suppose I were to write you a letter now. Would you know what date time I sent it out if I didn't state the Date Time in the letter?

Comment: So to analogize, If i was to ask to post office when the last letter coming from you was sent out, would they keep it on record or not?

Comment: Actually. How about just recording the time the packets were received. Since, even if I give it a latency of 999, as long as the packets do reach me, I give it at most a 10s lag time?